# Hibernate - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, log4j, runtime-error

I tried to run easy program with hibernate and HSQLDB.

I'm using `log4j` for this project with `log4j.properties`:

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Hibernate logging options (INFO only shows startup messages)
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log JDBC bind parameter runtime arguments
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INFO
```

and all is build with `Ant`, build file you can [see here](http://pastebin.com/x13SzwB0).

But when I run `schemaexport` target I caught next error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/nazar_art/workspace/Persistance/build.xml:64: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

[image: schemaexport error]

But I hasn't use `slf4j` why this caused?

here is my content of `lib` folder with all jars that It uses:

[image: lib struckture]

I couldn't figure out why does this happen?

Here is better project structure:

[image: project struckture]

**EDIT:**

I added `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar` but it throws:

> BUILD FAILED
>   /home/nazar_art/workspace/Persistance/build.xml:64: 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners

you can see here how it looks:

[image: entity listeners]

**How to solve this trouble?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate uses [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) internally to do its own logging. It is an abstraction layer on top of different logging implementations. Frameworks like using this facade because in this case you still stay independend from certain implementations. You can also make it work with log4j. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/) to make it work together.

Comment: I followed instructions from this tutorial but caught another trouble. I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate internally uses SLF4J for logging. Read the setup instructions here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-setup You need to keep `SLF4J jar` on the build and runtime classpath.

Comment: But at this link at maven dependency only SLF4J, without log4j. Why it doesn't only facade for logging (for log4j especially)?